# How to get notified when an <option selected> gets reselected?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onchange

See the code below. This is the navigation of a mobile site. Selecting a category loads the chosen category page, which lists all the products in that category. (E.g. selecting Fruits loads the `/fruits` category page, that lists links to apple, banana, orange etc.) When a product page is viewed, only the category name is shown in the `<select>`, instead of the product name. I want to make it possible to go back to the fruits category list from the apple product page, by selecting Fruits. But since it's already selected, the `change` event isn't fired. How else could I get notified about this action (when the currently selected item isn't changed, but selected again)?

```
<select onchange="location.href = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-href');">
    <option data-href="/vegetables">Vegetables
    <option data-href="/fruits" selected>Fruits
</select>
```

Comment: Maybe something with [blur](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur).

Comment: Unfortunatelly the `<select>` is not blurred when an item gets selected. Fortunatelly, I've figured out a workaround as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about such an event, but this trick works perfectly. The current category should be added to the `<select>` one more time, as a hidden option. Make this selected instead of the visible one, so a `change` event is fired even when selecting the current category.

```
<select onchange="location.href = event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-href');">
    <option hidden selected>Fruits
    <option data-href="/vegetables">Vegetables
    <option data-href="/fruits">Fruits
</select>
```